# Android studio given error when opened

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey I wanted to work on Lollipop 5.0. so I downloaded Android studio from android developers but it is giving error:

The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\;) does not point to valid JDK installation.

Can anyone please help.....

Comment: Update your JAVA SDK with 1.8.0

Comment: if u mean jdk then it is already 1.8

Comment: I am working the same in Android Lollipop with JAVA 1.7.2_55 and it's working fine. There is no error. Please check again all java HOME PATH configure properly in your system..

Answer (score 1):

If your Java home really is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\;` then remove the semicolon from the end of it; that's not a valid Windows path.